# Will Minecraft map items automatically update with terrain changes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I have a [map item](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map) filled out and covering a particular area, will it automatically detect changes in the terrain? Or will I have to revisit the area with a map?

Comment: Umm, guys, he could be asking about http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Map. Asking whether it shows terrain changes made after it's creation is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: That duplicate has absolutely nothing to do with my question. I mean a literal _map_ -- not the world.

Comment: That wasn't clear before the edit, now it is. I retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [official Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map):

> To record the world on a map, that specific map item must be held in the player's hands while the player moves around the world. **The world will be recorded as-is during exploration, meaning that if the world is modified, a player must revisit the area while holding the map in order to update the map's view**

So no, the map will not detect changes in the terrain unless you are in the area with the map to update it.